# RStudio cloud installed packages are not saved

Tags: r, rstudio

Whenever I start a new project I have to install tidyverse and lubridate packages all over again. I thought I just have to update packages but not install them every time I start a new project. What am I missing? Maybe I have to save installed packages somehow or? and when I run .libpath() and go to the packages directory it is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

So in RStudio Cloud you have to create a new workspace because there is no option to create a base project in the default workspace.

1. Create new workspace
2. New Project. download packages you need
3. Go back to your new workspace --> settings --> set as the base project.
   After these steps, all projects you create will include packages that you downloaded previously in your base project.

Comment: spent a lot of time googling and could not find the right answer. Thanks to RStudio community, problem solved.